# Prime factorization and ages

Tags: number-theory

> Tim is 23 years old and he has three younger siblings such that the product of their age is $156$. How old are Tim's siblings? Find all integer solutions.

So this seems to be a prime factorization problem? We can define $156$ as the product of $2^2\cdot3\cdot13 = 156$, but how should we use this info further?

Comment: Find all of the ways to split that into three factors, each of which is less than $23$.

Answer (score 1):

From the factorisation we know that Tim's siblings can only be of ages $1,2,3,4,6,12,13$. The $13$ cannot be paired with another prime factor without causing the product to go over Tim's age of $23$, so Tim has a $13$-year old sibling. The ages of the remaining two siblings then multiply to $12$, and can be determined easily, giving the solutions as
$$\{1,12,13\},\{2,6,13\},\{3,4,13\}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on this, how do we know that the siblings can be only of such ages?

Comment: @Viktor Just look over all divisors of $156$ - there are $12$ of them - and pick out those less than $23$.

Answer (score 0):

You have five prime factors of $156$:  $1,2,2,3,13$.  You must place them into exactly three sets, but you cannot put $13$ with any other factor, as that would give an age greater than Tim.

So we know that one age is $13$.

So, find the ways of splitting $1,2,2,3$ into two sets and you're done.